# How to determine the performance index M for the outer vessel of a vacuum bottle? Need help with objective and constraint selection (Ashby diagrams)

Tags: materials, design, manufacturing-engineering, material-science, ansys

I'm reaching out for assistance and advice regarding a problem I'm encountering in my thermal bottle analysis. I have been attempting to determine the performance index M but facing significant difficulties. I'm also concerned that I may have chosen the wrong objectives and constraints for my analysis.

Initially, I thought of including the objective "must be lightweight," but now I'm contemplating whether it would be more appropriate to replace it with the constraint "must withstand pressure differences." However, I'm a little bit lost on how to proceed with this change.

Here is my process:

Objective equation (I):
Minimize the heat flux J through the bottle wall.  = (∆/h) [J/m<sup>2</sup>.s] where ∆ is the temperature difference between the outside and the inside.

Constraint equation on weight (II):  =  [kg]

Constraint (III) in the objective equation (I):
 =  with  = h
⇔ (III)  = h ⇒ h = /()